# Postgresql: Find and replace multiple characters within parentheses in string

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column called SKETCH that contains vector strings varying in length, like the following:

"R24U26L24(LD26),"

Each string contains certain letters that should be followed by a number and there are parentheses() around any errors.

I want to find all the errors in each vector string - aka. any part of the string with a format like %(LD%)% or %(L%D)% [% being a wildcard] - and delete the pair of parentheses around the error, as well as any letter inside that has no number following it.

The result should look like this "R24U26L24**D26**,"

I've tried combining UPDATE, CASE ELSE, and REPLACE functions to run the different error criteria I have but have not succeeded. For example, the code I used below will replace the entire vector string with "%D%%" as text. Any help to figure this out is much appreciated.

```
UPDATE table
SET sketch = CASE 
WHEN sketch LIKE '%(LD%)%' THEN REPLACE(REPLACE('%(LD%)%', '(L', ''), ')', '')
WHEN sketch LIKE '%(RU%)%' THEN REPLACE(REPLACE('%(RU%)%', '(R', ''), ')', '')
WHEN sketch LIKE '%(L%U)%' THEN REPLACE(REPLACE('%(L%U)%', '(', ''), 'U)', '')
WHEN sketch LIKE '%(L%D)%' THEN REPLACE(REPLACE('%(L%D)%', '(', ''), 'D)', '')
ELSE sketch END;
```

Edit: This is the final fix that I used. Not as concise as I'd hoped but it works:

```
UPDATE table
SET sketch = regexp_replace(sketch, '\(LD([0-9]*)\)','D\1', 'g');

UPDATE table
SET sketch = regexp_replace(sketch, '\(RU([0-9]*)\)','U\1', 'g');

UPDATE table
SET sketch = regexp_replace(sketch, '\(L([0-9]*)U\)','L\1', 'g');

UPDATE table
SET sketch = regexp_replace(sketch, '\(L([0-9]*)D\)','L\1', 'g');
```

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try with:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET sketch = regexp_replace(sketch, '\(LD([0-9]*)\)','L\1');

UPDATE table_name
SET sketch = regexp_replace(sketch, '\(RU([0-9]*)\)','R\1');

UPDATE table_name
SET sketch = regexp_replace(sketch, '\(L([0-9]*)U\)','\1U');

UPDATE table_name
SET sketch = regexp_replace(sketch, '\(L([0-9]*)D\)','\1D');
```

It you want a single query, I guess one of these may works:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET sketch = (CASE
WHEN regexp_matches(sketch, '\(LD([0-9]*)\)') THEN regexp_replace(sketch, '\(LD([0-9]*)\)','L\1')
WHEN regexp_matches(sketch, '\(RU([0-9]*)\)') THEN regexp_replace(sketch, '\(RU([0-9]*)\)','R\1')
WHEN regexp_matches(sketch, '\(L([0-9]*)U\)') THEN regexp_replace(sketch, '\(L([0-9]*)U\)','\1U')
WHEN regexp_matches(sketch, '\(L([0-9]*)D\)') THEN regexp_replace(sketch, '\(L([0-9]*)D\)','\1D')
ELSE sketch END);
```

Or

```
UPDATE table_name
SET sketch = (CASE
WHEN sketch ~* '\(LD([0-9]*)\)' THEN regexp_replace(sketch, '\(LD([0-9]*)\)','L\1')
WHEN sketch ~* '\(RU([0-9]*)\)' THEN regexp_replace(sketch, '\(RU([0-9]*)\)','R\1')
WHEN sketch ~* '\(L([0-9]*)U\)' THEN regexp_replace(sketch, '\(L([0-9]*)U\)','\1U')
WHEN sketch ~* '\(L([0-9]*)D\)' THEN regexp_replace(sketch, '\(L([0-9]*)D\)','\1D')
ELSE sketch END);
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to switch the last part of the expression from  '(\1D)' to '(L\1)' in order to remove the letter with no number attached. Also, the parentheses are still there. Any idea of how to remove those in the same update as well?

Comment: The parenthesis, yes, sorry. I have insertes them in the solution. To remove the parentheses too, just remove it from the third param, for example: UPDATE table
SET sketch = regexp_replace(sketch, '\(LD([0-9]*)\)','L\1'); I will edit my response.

Comment: No worries! :) When I remove the parenthesis from the third param, for some reason it only works when there are four characters inside like (LD26) but not for (LD6). Also, the second query generally works but the first resulted in the following error message: set-returning functions are not allowed in UPDATE...WHEN regexp_matches.

Comment: I posted the final fix that I used above. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I'm happy for help!